# Binance limit short selling API: margin/order(sell) or margin/loan?

Tags: api, binance

I read their api doc. But I’m not sure if I want to short selling BTCUSDT, should I use its /margin/order’s sell limit api or /margin/loan api?

If answer is the second one, but how to I specify my limit price?

When I want to buy to cover or repay , which one should I use respectively?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this post
https://dev.binance.vision/t/margin-order-loan/639
It has clear explanation and uri link for you to use short selling

Comment: To be clearer. Short-selling is actually to loan an asset and the sell it immediately. To earn a profit, you buy it buy at a lower price and then repay the loan. By using Binance api, you can do it in two steps or one step.